# Trouble Updating Title in JInternalFrame GUI component

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, components, jinternalframe

i am trying to update the title of a JInternalFrame component in my Java Project.

The component is an instance of my ImageFrame class which extends JInternalFrame, and in my code I call a setter method in my ImageFrame class which updates the title attribute.  I ran a Unit test and know that the attribute is updating properly, but I can't figure out how to refresh the component to show the new title.

Any Ideas?

FYI: I was unable to get .repaint() to do the trick.

Here's the Code:

```
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();        // Gets File selected in JFileChooser
try {
    ImageReadWrite.write(img, selectedFile);              // Writes Image Data to a File
    frame.setFilePath(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());    // Changes File Location Attribute in Instance Of ImageFrame
    frame.setFileName(selectedFile.getName());            // Changes Window Title Attribute
    //frame.??
}
catch (Exception event) {
    event.printStackTrace();
}
```

so what I need here is to know what I should add to make the component update with the new title

Comment: Paste the code you're using to update the title. Ident using 4 spaces for autoformat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by replacing:

```
frame.setFileName(selectedFile.getName());
```

with

```
 frame.setTitle(selectedFile.getName());
```

I don't know your code, but setFileName is not part of JInternalFrame public interface.

Probably you added that method, probably not. Try my suggestion and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, .setFileName() is a setter method I wrote in my ImageFrame class, after reviewing i realized that while I had the code to change the attribute, I had no code to update the object.

so I tried your suggestion and got what I wanted.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great!, I suppose something like that had happened. That's why I ask you to paste your code to confirm it. It happens from time to time

Comment: Avoiding inheritance is a good way to avoid these sorts of bugs (and tends to produce very much better code).